# Reading Tarfile from URL

Tags: python, web-scraping, tar, tarfile

Trying to read tarfile from a URL

Mostly this scraping data from a website. Even tried using gzip to open the file but it produces similar the same error. Please suggest a solution for this.

```
import tarfile
from io import BytesIO
import urllib.request as urllib2

rt = urllib2.urlopen("https://opentender.eu/data/files/CY_ocds_data.json.tar.gz").read()
csvzip = tarfile.open(BytesIO(rt),mode='r:gz')
```

This is producing type error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-2ed9e3f5bdd6> in <module>()
      4 import urllib.request as urllib2
      5 rt = urllib2.urlopen("https://opentender.eu/data/files/CY_ocds_data.json.tar.gz").read()
----> 6 csvzip = tarfile.open(BytesIO(rt),mode='r:gz')
      7 # csvzip.printdir()

2 frames
/usr/lib/python3.7/gzip.py in __init__(self, filename, mode, compresslevel, fileobj, mtime)
    166             mode += 'b'
    167         if fileobj is None:
--> 168             fileobj = self.myfileobj = builtins.open(filename, mode or 'rb')
    169         if filename is None:
    170             filename = getattr(fileobj, 'name', '')

TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.BytesIO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call `tarfile.open` with the `fileobj` keyword argument:

```
csvzip = tarfile.open(fileobj=BytesIO(rt),mode='r:gz')
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this would be better:

```
import tarfile
import urllib.request as urllib2

rt = urllib2.urlopen("https://opentender.eu/data/files/CY_ocds_data.json.tar.gz")
csvzip = tarfile.open(fileobj=rt,mode='r:gz')
```

The urlopen function returns a file object and you pass it to tarfile.open.

Bobby

Answer (score 0):

Sharing an alternative that supports Basic authentication:

```
import tarfile
from io import BytesIO
import requests
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter, Retry


def session_get(url, user, passw):
    session = requests.session()
    retries = Retry(total=5, backoff_factor=0.5, status_forcelist=[403, 502, 503, 504])
    session.mount('https://', HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))
    response = session.get(url, auth=(user, passw))
    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception(log(f'Unable to access link:\n{url}\nError code: {response.status_code}'))
    return response


url = "https://opentender.eu/data/files/CY_ocds_data.json.tar.gz"
resp = session_get(url, '<username>', '<password>')
tf = tarfile.open(fileobj=BytesIO(resp.content), mode="r:gz")
tf.extractfile('<filename>').read()
```